# Piecewise highlighting in beamer presentation with sub bullets

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, highlighting

I want to piecewise highlight the items of an `itemsize` and gray out previous items. For this task, i use the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamercovered{again covered={\opaqueness<1->{30}}}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}[<+>]
\item A
\item B
\item C
\begin{itemize}
\item CA
\item CB
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Now the problem is that CA and CB are not properly grayed out. I want to them to gray out as if they were items of the parent `itemize`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for posting a nice minimal example with your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Possibility:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamercovered{again covered={\opaqueness<1->{30}}}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}[<+>]
\item A
\item B
\item<.-> C
\begin{itemize}
\item CA
\item CB
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Second possibility:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamercovered{again covered={\opaqueness<1->{30}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}[<+>]
\item A
\item B
\item C
\item<.->[]
\begin{itemize}
\item CA
\item CB
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to gray out C while CA and CB are displayed?

Comment: @K.Sama Please see my updated answer.